# select duplicates from data based on another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table and would like to select one row of the duplicates.  The table has multiple columns that adds up to identify as duplicates

review the excel table data.

[image]   a short image of the table with data.    Ther result should be

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To make your data useful **edit your question** to post it as **text**, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Also, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) as well as the attempt you made to solve the problem and where you went wrong.

Comment: What happened when you used the `Remove Duplicates` tool?